# New drive letter mapped to an existing folder for read-only access, in Win XP

Tags: windows-xp

How can get a new drive letter mapped to an existing folder, such that access is read-only?

Comment: The answer can be found on ServerFault, [here][1].



  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/280747/use-net-use-to-mount-a-network-drive-as-read-only

Answer (score 1):

I think you can share that folder with read only permissions after **disabling** "[Simple file sharing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307874)" and then [mapping the corresponding network folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308582) to a specific drive letter. Please let me know if that works :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not mess with the file sharing settings if possible. Is there nothing like SUBST with read-only?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a thing. Maybe others can help. Still, I think the file sharing approach should be very easy to do, and it works just fine in Windows 7 :)

Comment: Thanks. I don't doubt the file sharing solution would work, but it would prang anything relying on Simple file sharing.

Comment: That's also true :)